# How can I find out if getDate() is between 2 time(7) timestamps?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an application that sends alerts if the temperature exceeds limits, but I only want to send alerts if it happens at certain times of the day.  I'm using time(7) datatype to store those times.  I need it to be flexible enough to cross midnight, so I could have the following times:

```
time_on   time_off
08:00:00  17:00:00
00:00:00  12:00:00
21:00:00  09:00:00
```

How can I figure out if CONVERT(time(7), getdate()) is between any of those combinations?

Comment: has your table a date field?

Comment: @zerkms Adding 24 hours to a [`Time(7)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql) is problematic since it can only contain a time _less than_ 24 hours. A larger range would have made many tasks much easier.

Comment: @HABO good to know, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add TIME to a datetime value.  Here we truncate the current GetDate() to midnight via `Declare @D datetime = convert(date,GetDate())`

```
Declare @YourTable table (time_on time,time_off time)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('08:00:00','17:00:00'), 
('00:00:00','12:00:00'),
('21:00:00','09:00:00'),
('00:00:00','12:00:00'),   -- Added for illustration
('12:00:00','00:00:00')    -- Added for illustration


Declare @D datetime = convert(date,GetDate())

Select *
 From  @YourTable
 Where GetDate() >= @D+convert(datetime,time_on)
   and GetDate() <= @D+convert(datetime,time_off)+case when time_off<=time_on then 1 else 0 end
```

**Returns**

```
time_on             time_off
12:00:00.0000000    00:00:00.0000000
```

My current Datetime was 2017-04-02 18:33:53.803 which did not satisfy any of the original criteria, so I added two records for illustration

**Or,** if you don't want to declare **@D**

```
Select *
 From  @YourTable
 Where GetDate() >= convert(datetime,convert(date,GetDate()))+convert(datetime,time_on)
   and GetDate() <= convert(datetime,convert(date,GetDate()))+convert(datetime,time_off)+case when time_off<=time_on then 1 else 0 end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select a.*
from alerttimes a
where (time_on <= time_off and cast(getdate() as time) >= time_on and cast(getdate() as time) < time_off) or
      (time_on > time_off and cast(getdate() as time) <= time_on and cast(getdate() as time) >= time_off);
```

This handles the issue with your table, which is that some period include midnight.